# Vim: Append to end of line, but add a space if there is no space

Tags: vim

Sort of new to Vim here. I've been using Vim to practice first on Markdown before I get to Ruby which is my day job. I frequently run across this problem:

```
My sentence is this._
My sentence is this.
```

In the first example, I have a "space" signified by the _. I can press A to append and type the next sentence. But I also have a "no space" case at the end where after I press A I have to press spacebar before I type stuff. How do I add space then append in one keystroke?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to this is through *mappings*. With `:help map-expr`, you can even build a mapping that resolves to `A` when there's already a trailing space, and to `A<Space>` if not. With `:nnoremap <buffer> ...`, you can limit the mapping to the current Markdown file. Nonetheless, I'm not convinced that this mapping is beneficial in general (or even just to Markdown files); there will still be many situations when you need to append without a space separator, so overriding the `A` command is out of the question, you still need that.

The amount of quick-to-type single key mappings is very limited (most are already taken), and in the best case, you're saving just one key press (that of the Space key). While mappings can make you more productive, this isn't one of them. Keep inserting that space manually (as you still will in other applications), and save up that mapping for a more valuable target!

Comment: Thank you for the well-thought out answer. I'm convinced by the "you still will in other applications" argument. I guess I'll stick through with it for now!

Answer (score 1):

You can remap `A` to `A<space>`, add the following to your `.vimrc`. Now when you press `A`, it will add a space to the end of line and then you can append anything you want.

```
nnoremap A A<space>
```

Comment: Thanks @Amit for answering. I will admit that I haven't touched the `vimrc` file yet, I plan on working with the constraints of the default keys for a few weeks first. I will probably do this, with an if statement so it doesn't double add, and only for markdown files. Is there a way to do this without editing vimrc though?

Comment: @DaryllSantos Yes, in your current buffer you can type `:nnoremap A A_` to activate this mapping but that will be active only for current session.

Comment: You can write `A<Space>` (also in your .vimrc); that's more clear and avoids the risk of accidentally clearing the trailing space during a later edit.